# error 30 firebase database and Authentication for Android on build gradle

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have problem with add `firebase` database and Authentication for Android on build `gradle`.

[image]

Comment: Try clean Project.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this to your *build.gradle* from the application.

`buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}`

And the, into your **app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Take a look at this post from google.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Can you add yout build.gradle and app/build.gradle to your post?